# OnInfoWindowClickListener implementation

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have been attempting to use OnInfoWindowClickListener so when a user taps the info window of my marker, it takes them to an another activity I named PageActivity. However, all the implementations I have found online do not seem to work, and the layout  provided on the google maps api documentation did not seem to work either. 
Furthermore, the line 
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
at the bottom of the code, come up red, especially new OnInfoWindowClickListener()

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera

    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0,0)).title("Lets try this").snippet("gotcha"));
    //LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    //mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    //double user_latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
    //double user_longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
    //LatLng user_coord = new LatLng(user_latitude, user_longitude);

    //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(user_latitude,user_longitude)).title("You are here"));
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null) {

        LatLng target = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        CameraPosition position = this.mMap.getCameraPosition();

        CameraPosition.Builder builder = new CameraPosition.Builder();
        builder.zoom(15);
        builder.target(target);

        this.mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(builder.build()));
        //Marker our_marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).title("Local Bathroom").snippet("Tap for Rating").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, DummyContent.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } });
    }

    //LatLng New_york = new LatLng(40, -73);
    LatLng netherlands = new LatLng(40.715613, -73.604853);
    LatLng studentcenter1 = new LatLng(40.715946, -73.602037);
    LatLng studentcenter2 = new LatLng(40.716231, -73.601007);
    LatLng bits = new LatLng(40.713889, -73.601651);
    LatLng playhouse = new LatLng(40.713043, -73.600707);
    LatLng calkins = new LatLng(40.713303, -73.599977);
    LatLng axinn = new LatLng(40.714824, -73.600492);
    LatLng library = new LatLng(40.714609, -73.601116);
    LatLng alliance = new LatLng(40.716502, -73.602183);
    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(New_york).title("Welcome to the city!!"));
    Marker alliance_marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(alliance).title("Alliance Hall's Bathroom").snippet("Tap for Rating").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.finaltoilet)));
    Marker library_marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(library).title("Axinn Library's Bathroom").snippet("Tap for Rating").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.finaltoilet)));
    Marker Hammer_marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(axinn).title("Hammer Lab's Bathroom").snippet("Tap for Rating").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.finaltoilet)));
    Marker calkins_marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(calkins).title("Calkins Hall's Bathroom").snippet("Tap for Rating").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.finaltoilet)));
    Marker playhouse_marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(playhouse).title("Playhouse's Bathroom").snippet("Tap for Rating").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.finaltoilet)));
    Marker bits_marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(bits).title("Bits and Bite's Bathroom").snippet("Tap for Rating").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.finaltoilet)));
    Marker studentcenter2_marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(studentcenter2).title("Game Room's Bathroom").snippet("Tap for Rating").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.finaltoilet)));
    Marker studentcenter1_marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(studentcenter1).title("Student Center's Bathroom").snippet("Tap for Rating").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.finaltoilet)));
    Marker netherlands_marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(netherlands).title("Netherland's Bathroom").snippet("Tap for Rating").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.finaltoilet)));
    Marker our_marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).title("Local Bathroom").snippet("Tap for Rating").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.finaltoilet)));
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener((GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener) this);
    //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(New_york));
}
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, PageActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra bracket if your code is exact as posted, thats why `mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener` is red

try removing `{` before `mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener` line and listener should work